# Burninate tag: process scheduling

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags

Somebody convince me that tags for scheduling and process (or operating-system, or similar) wouldn't be just as good. Go on, let's hear it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Process scheduling in the OS is a most special special case of general scheduling problems in that you can assume lots of nice things. I guess you could remove [process-scheduling](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/process-scheduling) in favor of [scheduling](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scheduling) + [operating-systems](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/operating-systems); I think that people looking for (general) scheduling problems would perceive such questions as noise, though. From what I remember of the scheduling theory lecture I took and what people ask under [process-scheduling](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/process-scheduling), these are two different and largely separate worlds. Therefore I created the tag, and vote for it to stay.

Comment: [Last time round](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/156/the-scheduling-tag), you argued the other way! +1 here, since I agree with you, these are very separate worlds that use vaguely related concepts with the same name.

Comment: @Gilles: Hu, weird. Funny how opinions change. Reading my reasoning from back then, it still does make sense. I guess I changed my viewpoint on this from a "tags as classification" to "tags as searching tool".